# Get an error after adding a new language

Tags: jhipster

After adding a new language with the command "yo jhipster:langaugues", I get the following error with grunt test. Those errors are at bower_components which I already exclude from the project on Intellij Idea. Is something I didn't do it right or a problem within JHister?

```
C:\Users\me/projects/myapp>grunt test
Running "clean:server" (clean) task
>> 0 paths cleaned.

Running "wiredep:test" (wiredep) task

Running "ngconstant:dev" (ngconstant) task 
Creating module yellowflowApp at src/main/webapp/scripts/app/app.constants.js...OK

Running "karma:unit" (karma) task
INFO [karma]: Karma v0.12.35 server started at http://localhost:9876/
INFO [launcher]: Starting browser PhantomJS
INFO [PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Windows 7 0.0.0)]: Connected on socket FPQ9_PnLvN3UNXN4CjH4 with id 99835325
PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Windows 7 0.0.0): Executed 14 of 21 SUCCESS (0 secs / 0.155 secs)
PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Windows 7 0.0.0) Directive Tests  Password strength Should display the password strength bar FAILED
    Error: Unexpected request: GET i18n/zh-cn/global.json
    Expected GET i18n/en/global.json
        at $httpBackend (C:/Users/me/projects/myapp/src/main/webapp/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:1212)
        at sendReq (C:/Users/me/projects/myapp/src/main/webapp/bower_components/angular/angular.js:10233)
        at C:/Users/me/projects/myapp/src/main/webapp/bower_components/angular/angular.js:9944
        at processQueue (C:/Users/me/projects/myapp/src/main/webapp/bower_components/angular/angular.js:14454)
        at C:/Users/me/projects/myapp/src/main/webapp/bower_components/angular/angular.js:14470
        at C:/Users/me/projects/myapp/src/main/webapp/bower_components/angular/angular.js:15719
        at C:/Users/me/projects/myapp/src/main/webapp/bower_components/angular/angular.js:15530
        at C:/Users/me/projects/myapp/src/main/webapp/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:1510
        at C:/Users/me/projects/myapp/src/test/javascript/spec/app/account/password/password.directive.spec.js:27
PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Windows 7 0.0.0) Directive Tests  Password strength Should change the first 2 points of the strength bar FAILED
    Error: Unexpected request: GET i18n/zh-cn/global.json
    Expected GET i18n/en/global.json
        at $httpBackend (C:/Users/me/projects/myapp/src/main/webapp/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:1212)
        at sendReq (C:/Users/me/projects/myapp/src/main/webapp/bower_components/angular/angular.js:10233)
        at C:/Users/me/projects/myapp/src/main/webapp/bower_components/angular/angular.js:9944
        at processQueue (C:/Users/me/projects/myapp/src/main/webapp/bower_components/angular/angular.js:14454)
        at C:/Users/me/projects/myapp/src/main/webapp/bower_components/angular/angular.js:14470
        at C:/Users/me/projects/myapp/src/main/webapp/bower_components/angular/angular.js:15719
        at C:/Users/me/projects/myapp/src/main/webapp/bower_components/angular/angular.js:15530
        at C:/Users/me/projects/myapp/src/main/webapp/bower_components/angular/angular.js:15824
        at C:/Users/me/projects/myapp/src/test/javascript/spec/app/account/password/password.directive.spec.js:41
    Error: [$rootScope:inprog] $digest already in progress
    http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.0/$rootScope/inprog?p0=%24digest
        at beginPhase (C:/Users/me/projects/myapp/src/main/webapp/bower_components/angular/angular.js:16073)
        at C:/Users/me/projects/myapp/src/main/webapp/bower_components/angular/angular.js:15510
        at C:/Users/me/projects/myapp/src/main/webapp/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:1510
        at C:/Users/me/projects/myapp/src/test/javascript/spec/app/account/password/password.directive.spec.js:27
PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Windows 7 0.0.0) Directive Tests  Password strength Should change the first 4 points of the strength bar FAILED
    Error: Unexpected request: GET i18n/zh-cn/global.json
    Expected GET i18n/en/global.json
        at $httpBackend (C:/Users/me/projects/myapp/src/main/webapp/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:1212)
        at sendReq (C:/Users/me/projects/myapp/src/main/webapp/bower_components/angular/angular.js:10233)
        at C:/Users/me/projects/myapp/src/main/webapp/bower_components/angular/angular.js:9944
        at processQueue (C:/Users/me/projects/myapp/src/main/webapp/bower_components/angular/angular.js:14454)
        at C:/Users/me/projects/myapp/src/main/webapp/bower_components/angular/angular.js:14470
        at C:/Users/me/projects/myapp/src/main/webapp/bower_components/angular/angular.js:15719
        at C:/Users/me/projects/myapp/src/main/webapp/bower_components/angular/angular.js:15530
        at C:/Users/me/projects/myapp/src/main/webapp/bower_components/angular/angular.js:15824
        at C:/Users/me/projects/myapp/src/test/javascript/spec/app/account/password/password.directive.spec.js:56
    Error: [$rootScope:inprog] $digest already in progress
    http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.0/$rootScope/inprog?p0=%24digest
        at beginPhase (C:/Users/me/projects/myapp/src/main/webapp/bower_components/angular/angular.js:16073)
        at C:/Users/me/projects/myapp/src/main/webapp/bower_components/angular/angular.js:15510
        at C:/Users/me/projects/myapp/src/main/webapp/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:1510
        at C:/Users/me/projects/myapp/src/test/javascript/spec/app/account/password/password.directive.spec.js:27
PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Windows 7 0.0.0) Services Tests  Auth should call LocalStorageService.clearAll on logout FAILED
    Error: Unexpected request: GET i18n/zh-cn/global.json
    Expected GET i18n/en/global.json
        at $httpBackend (C:/Users/me/projects/myapp/src/main/webapp/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:1212)
        at sendReq (C:/Users/me/projects/myapp/src/main/webapp/bower_components/angular/angular.js:10233)
        at C:/Users/me/projects/myapp/src/main/webapp/bower_components/angular/angular.js:9944
        at processQueue (C:/Users/me/projects/myapp/src/main/webapp/bower_components/angular/angular.js:14454)
        at C:/Users/me/projects/myapp/src/main/webapp/bower_components/angular/angular.js:14470
        at C:/Users/me/projects/myapp/src/main/webapp/bower_components/angular/angular.js:15719
        at C:/Users/me/projects/myapp/src/main/webapp/bower_components/angular/angular.js:15530
        at C:/Users/me/projects/myapp/src/main/webapp/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:1510
        at C:/Users/me/projects/myapp/src/test/javascript/spec/components/auth/auth.services.spec.js:39
    Error: [$rootScope:inprog] $digest already in progress
    http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.0/$rootScope/inprog?p0=%24digest
        at beginPhase (C:/Users/me/projects/myapp/src/main/webapp/bower_components/angular/angular.js:16073)
        at C:/Users/me/projects/myapp/src/main/webapp/bower_components/angular/angular.js:15510
        at C:/Users/me/projects/myapp/src/main/webapp/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:1542
        at C:/Users/me/projects/myapp/src/test/javascript/spec/components/auth/auth.services.spec.js:27
PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Windows 7 0.0.0): Executed 21 of 21 (4 FAILED) (0.282 secs / 0.256 secs)
Warning: Task "karma:unit" failed. Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.

Execution Time (2015-07-16 18:04:35 UTC)
wiredep:test   3.8s  █████████████████████ 23%
karma:unit    12.6s  ███████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████ 76%
Total 16.5s
```

Comment: Looks like a bug to me, can you open up a ticket?

Answer (score 0):

For recent versions of jHipster this problem should not be occurring anymore, because there is now a regular expression that does not take into account the language in the path.
For older versions though, if you changed the default language then you must adapt password.directive.spec.js and auth.services.spec.js in order to expect the (now different) default language. Those lines are similar to this:

```
$httpBackend.expectGET('i18n/en/global.json').respond({});
```

(Notice "/en/" in the path, that part is the one that should match the current default language).

Comment: I can't see what shall be changed in those two files. Can you provide some details?